# How to externalize a MouseListener?

Tags: java, swing, listener

(**Note:** I am aware of the existence of the `MouseAdapter`-class, but since I am probably overriding all methods later on, the advantage of it is lost?)

I have a class MainProgram.java in which I'm adding several components. Most of them have a Listener (ActionListener, MouseListener, ...), which get's a bit crowded in my main class.

Therefore I am trying to "externalize" those Listeners into their own classes. So far I have used inner classes in my main-class, which makes accessing the variables, components, ... pretty easy and straightforward.

But with the external Listeners I am not sure what is the best way to implement them.

For example, when I want to find out, which of the lables has been clicked, I am getting the event, get the source of the event, cast it to a `JLabel` and then get the text on the label with which I compare a string!

This works, but seems very prone to errors (what if I change the JLabel-text in my main-class? -> Listener breaks) and pretty unclean.

I've tried to search via google and on StackOverflow for better ways to do this, but only found the inner class approach.

So is there a better way to get access to my components / externalize my listeners?

```
public class MainProgram extends JFrame {
    public MainProgram() {
        super("Landing Page");
        setSize(400, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel westPanel = new JPanel();

        JLabel lbl_orderStatus = new JLabel("Order Status");
        JLabel lbl_technicalDocu = new JLabel("Technical Documentation");
        JLabel lbl_checkReport = new JLabel("Check Report");

        MouseListenerBoldFont mouseListenerLabelBoldPlain = new MouseListenerBoldFont();

        lbl_orderStatus.addMouseListener(mouseListenerLabelBoldPlain);
        lbl_technicalDocu.addMouseListener(mouseListenerLabelBoldPlain);
        lbl_checkReport.addMouseListener(mouseListenerLabelBoldPlain);

        westPanel.add(lbl_orderStatus);
        westPanel.add(lbl_technicalDocu);
        westPanel.add(lbl_checkReport);
        add(westPanel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                MainProgram window = new MainProgram();
                window.setVisible(true);
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The **MouseListenerBoldFont.java**:

```
public class MouseListenerBoldFont implements MouseListener{

    Object lbl_westPanel;

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if(((JLabel)e.getSource()).getText().equals("Order Status")){
            System.out.println("Order Status clicked");
        };
        if(((JLabel)e.getSource()).getText().equals("Technical Documentation")){
            System.out.println("Technical Documentation clicked");
        };
        if(((JLabel)e.getSource()).getText().equals("Check Report")){
            System.out.println("Check Report clicked");
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        lbl_westPanel = e.getSource();
        ((JComponent) lbl_westPanel).setFont(new Font("tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        lbl_westPanel = e.getSource();
        ((JComponent) lbl_westPanel).setFont(new Font("tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {    
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Part of the problem is the use of JLabels as buttons.  JLabels aren't really designed to be clicked like buttons.  If you use JButton, then in your ActionListener you can use getActionCommand() instead of the displayed text of the component.  Better yet create constants to compare against your action commands.  If you do this, I think the headache of externalizing your listeners will fade away.

Comment: To go further with the comment by @whiskeyspider, this topic shows the use of JButton looking like a JLabel : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635126/which-jlabel-has-been-clicked

Comment: Comparing `Strings` via `==` is very dangerous. Use `equals()` instead (since `Strings` are objects).

Comment: @tucuxi: You're right, I've changed that in my code.

Comment: If you want to externalise the listeners the consider providing a listener per component, this way you can specialise the functionality for the component (or type of operation the component is doing)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: You mean i.e. `button1` has `listener1`, `button2` has `listener2` and so on and all the listeners are in their own class?

Comment: @hamena314 If the functionality for `button1` is different from `button2` then yes

Comment: @whiskeyspider: Nice idea to use `JButtons` instead of `JLabels`. Seems to work so far, are there any downsides of changing the `JButtons` thich much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure this is not the best way but may be useful for your problem

```
public class MyLabel extends JLabel implements MouseListener {
    public MyLabel() {
        addMouseListener(this);
    }
    public MyLabel(String txt) {
        super(txt);
        addMouseListener(this);
    }
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println(getText() + " clicked");
    }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        setFont(new Font("tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
    }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        setFont(new Font("tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { }
}
```

then

```
    JLabel lbl_orderStatus = new MyLabel("Order Status");
    JLabel lbl_technicalDocu = new MyLabel("Technical Documentation");
    JLabel lbl_checkReport = new MyLabel("Check Report");

//        MouseListenerBoldFont mouseListenerLabelBoldPlain = new MouseListenerBoldFont();
//
//        lbl_orderStatus.addMouseListener(mouseListenerLabelBoldPlain);
//        lbl_technicalDocu.addMouseListener(mouseListenerLabelBoldPlain);
//        lbl_checkReport.addMouseListener(mouseListenerLabelBoldPlain);
```

Comment: Interesting idea to create a new type of label, but wouldn't this still have the problem of still having to compare strings? For example in the `mouseClicked()`-method, what if I want to use several `ifs`? Like `if(getText().equals("Order Status") ... do this ... if(getText().equals("Check report") ... do that ...` ?

Comment: @hamena314, every label have its own mouselistener which listens for its label's click events, so no need to compare strings. mouseClicked of lbl_orderStatus will only be invoked when clicked on only lbl_orderStatus.

Comment: I've decided to use this approach, as it is quite simple (and lazy: you dont even need to type `component.addMouseListener`...). But in your answer you've written "this is not the best way", could you elaborate? I dont see the downside of this approach (yet).

Comment: if you want to call a common logic (eg onmouseover) then a second mouselistener may be ndeeded... this may be a downside

Comment: Found another minor downside: As you are extending from (to?) `JLabel`, you can not extend also from (to?) `MouseAdapter`. Instead you have to implement `MouseListener` and all of its methods, regardless if you need them or not.

Comment: Another question: How can you distinguish between the sources? I.e. if someone clicks "Order Status" color the page blue, if someone clicks "Technical Documentation" color the page red, because I am not able to implement that. When I want to check for the source-label, I cant use an `if`, since the declaration of the labels is after the new label-class.

Comment: public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {   System.out.println(getText() + " clicked");  getParent.setBackGround(myColor);}  where myColor is an instance variable which is set in the constructor. this way you have to change constructors of MyLabel(Color color), MyLabel(Color color, String text)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101901/discussion-between-hamena314-and-guleryuz).

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to write inline (anonymous-class) handlers that forward the actual handling to another, non-anonymous function. This would give you something like:

```
    JLabel lblOrderStatus = new JLabel("Order Status");
    lblOrderStatus.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) { 
            doWhateverClickOnOrderStatusRequires();
        }
    });

    // much later
    private void doWhateverClickOnOrderStatusRequires() { ... }
```

The name of the external not-quite-handler method (`doWhateverClickOnOrderStatusRequires`) should capture the task that it attempts to achieve (for example, `launchRockets`); and with this pattern, you can call the same not-quite-handler method from multiple handlers. Since the compiler will check that the calls are valid a compile-time, there are no fragile string-constants involved.

Comment: Indeed this get's rid of the fragile strings, but wouldn't this still be in the main class and therefore if I have a lot of logic-code (several if-conditions for example) still bloat my main class?

Comment: I tend to write one class for the UI (more if parts of the UI are complex enough), and launch it from the main class. Main classes should generally only do the launching, but not contain the code to be launched. The not-quite-handler methods should then call the relevant domain-model code, which should know nothing at all about the existence of a UI: look up model-view-controller separation; which is often reduced to model-view+controller, with V&C rolled into one.

Comment: You would not need any "if-conditions" when using this pattern (or at least, not to decide which label had been pressed). As guleryuz pointed out, if you have a bunch of components that subclass X and behave the same, by all means, write a subclass of X that includes the behaviour baked in, to avoid any duplication.

Comment: Now I understand: You are able to "plug-in" external methods into the handler, which saves code as you can combine the methods and the handlers however suits you ... however I dont know how I could externalise this concept into another class. Would I need to write a new class, that contains those external methods?

Comment: I do not understand your comment. You do not "externalize" things just for the joy of it - you add new classes to embody new concepts, or to subdivide the responsibilities of existing ones. "How to externalize" depends on "why externalize". The above approach works for any number of classes, and simply decouples listeners from their actions in a safe, readable way.

Comment: I dont doubt that. Maybe I am just not fully understanding the approach, I simply do not know, how those classes would have to look when you divide them. Or in other words: how do I connect the external classes into my main class?

Answer (score 0):

You probably still want to use a class which extends MouseAdapter, since it can be used as a MouseListener, a MouseMotionListener, and a MouseWheelListener all at once (You just have to add it as all of those into a component). I'm not sure why you need to get the text on a JLabel to detect if it's the one that has been clicked. You should create a class which extends MouseAdapter and make it solely for JLabels, then add it to that JLabel. You should define a custom constructor if you want that takes a JLabel for an argument so that it will automatically know what JLabel is being interacted with. You can then add a method which passes an event to the main class.

Comment: Is this solution going in the same direction as @guleryuz? Then what if I have several if-conditions. Wouldn't it then still be necessary to compare the strings?

Comment: I had answered before @guleryuz, but his solution would probably work too. If you really need to compare the strings, mine would work as the class extending MouseAdapter would have the JLabel in it, and could get the string from it.